# Terminate a confirm window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

How can I terminate a Javascript pop up condirm window , when I use return the pop up window doesnt appear at all...is any other option that I can terminate the pop up windows without the return ..I have tryed everything endSession, window.close(), return any more idea

```
  var temp= confirm('<%=message%>');
    while(temp){
            var temp= confirm('<%=message%>');
    }

<%if(message.equals(osmessage.getMessage("ORD7009")) && repeatWindow == 1){%>
document.location.reload(true);

<% repeatWindow++;  
allowDelete = true;

}%>`
```

any more ideas ..by clicking OK the user I want the confirm button always there stay until gives CANCEL

Comment: Is this Java, if not, why is there a Java tag?

Comment: JSP I presume, but irrelevant in this case

Comment: What is the sense of a confirm then? Why not use alert?

Comment: its part of java code from a jsp page this javascript code

Comment: No, you cannot kill a `confirm()` window, it is blocking and will only terminate when the user clicks the button.

Comment: because every time takes another message ...one confirm box many error messages

Comment: I think you badly messed up what's going on server side and what's happening client side.

Comment: havent implementiert ..just need to fix it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confirm dialog box is totally under control of the browser until the user has made it's choice. You can't close it programmatically once it has been opened.

"Return" means: the user has confirmed - - which is the same as clicking on "ok".

Thus: "works as designed".

As from the JSP, I presume, the following is happening:

1. Page opens
2. confirm dialog opens
3. on "ok" (how ever by return or click) the line
   `document.location.reload(true);` is reached, and
4. the page reloads, starting over showing a confirm box.

In order to break out of this infinite loop, there's nothing with the confirm boxes but with your end condition which is in here:

```
<%if(message.equals(osmessage.getMessage("ORD7009")) && repeatWindow == 1){%>
document.location.reload(true);

<% repeatWindow++;  
allowDelete = true;

}%>`
```

and which probably does not reach an end in order to skip printing the redirect line.

Comment: Is any option or way that can I terminate the confirm window after user click CANCEL

Comment: After the user has clicked or hit any key, the window _IS_ closed before any of your script will resume running.

Comment: what can I do..any Idea?